# AWS SDK for PHP: how to retry asynchronous failures?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, guzzle, amazon-polly

I am using AWS Polly with AWS SDK for PHP in async mode.

Polly has a rate limit of 80 per second, whereas I want to be able to burst and do more than that, and in case their API returns 503 Rate Limiting, I want to retry the request (my script works fine if under rate limit).

The docs state there's a [retries option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html#retries), but it does nothing: it doesn't matter if i set it to 0 or 1000, it doesn't seem to retry and I get rejected promises from the SDK. Maybe it's only good for synchronous request?

```
$polly = new PollyClient($config);

// $config
array (size=4)
  'version' => string 'latest' (length=6)
  'credentials' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'xxx' (length=20)
      'secret' => string 'xxx' (length=40)
  'region' => string 'eu-west-1' (length=9)
  'retries' => int 1000
```

Do note that `unwrap`ing the returned promises in correct order is important too (e.g. responses should be in the same order as requests).

I suppose this code is not really important, but here it is anyway

```
foreach ($textChunks as $textChunk) {
    try {
        $promise = $promises[] = $polly->synthesizeSpeechAsync([
            'OutputFormat' => 'mp3',
            'Text' => $textChunk,
            'TextType' => 'text',
            'VoiceId' => 'Amy',
        ]);

        $promise->then(
            function() use () {
                // resolved
            },
            function() {
                // rejected
            }
        );
    } catch (PollyException $e) {
        // log
    }
}

try {
    $results = GuzzleHttp\Promise\unwrap($promises);
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    // log
}
```

Comment: What about using [`CommandPool`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/commands.html#command-pool) to keep the number of simultaneous requests to a sane level?  AWS may frown on applications that repeatedly trigger throttling.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Hey, thanks for the awesome advice. I did exactly that, therefore managing to set the maximum concurrency limit. However, what this does is lowers the probability of getting rate limited, but it still doesn't let me retry rejected promises.

Comment: I'm honestly not that familiar with the SDK for PHP, or PHP best practices/design patterns in general... but the SDK source code should give you some idea if it's designed to handle retried with promises or if the expectation is that you would handle them (perhaps by sending the request back to the command pool, which I assume keeps going until it runs out of things to do).  It also could be that this is an issue with what kinds of failures qualify for retries.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1214) with AWS PHP SDK developer:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1214#issuecomment-292002487

> All async requests if failed are automatically retried.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1214#issuecomment-301609123

> PHP SDK will use multi_curl for sending async requests. A new request is retried when a previous once fails and hence the order is preserved until it's scheduled using multi_curl.